# Как сделать подсчет количества переходов по ссылке? Видает ошибку "undefined method `number' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Я создал миграцию :**

```
class AddNumberToGame < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :games, :number, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

**Внес изменения в routes.rb :**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :games do
    get :number_lost, on: :collection
    get :number_win, on: :collection
  end
end
```

**games_controller.rb :**

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_game, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :number_lost, :number_win]


  def index
    @a = Array(1..25)
    @d = number_nil

    @games = Game.all
  end

def number_lost
    @game.increment!(:number)
    redirect_to action: :index
  end

  def number_win
    @game.increment!(:number)
    redirect_to action: :index
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_game
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def game_params
    params[:game]
  end

  def number_nil
    mas = Array(1..25)
    mas.sort_by{rand}
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb :**

```
    <div class="container">
        <% @d.each do |i| %>
            <% if i == 12 %>
                <div class="count_win"><h1><%= link_to 'Win' %></h1></div>
            <% else %>
                <div class="count_lost"><h1><%= link_to 'Lost', number_lost_games_url(i) %> </h1></div>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <p>Неправельний ответ : <%= @game.number %></p>
```

**У меня випадает ошибка :**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `number' for nil:NilClass):
    19:         <% end %>
    20:     </div>
    21: 
    22:     <p>Неправельний ответ : <%= @game.number %></p>
    23: 
    24:     <% @games.each do |game| %>
    25:         <tr>
  app/views/games/index.html.erb:22:in `_app_views_games_index_html_erb__510322269_48762876'
```

**Подскажите, где моя ошибка?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ошибка била здесь :**

```
  def game_params
    params[:game]
  end
```

**я изменил и все заработало :**

```
  def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:number)
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
    <div class="container">
        <% @d.each do |i| %>
            <% if i == 12 %>
                <div class="count_win"><h1><%= link_to 'Win', number_win_game_path(1) %></h1></div>
            <% else %>
                <div class="count_lost"><h1> <%= link_to 'Lost', number_lost_game_path(1) %></h1></div>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>


    <p>Неправельний ответ : <%= @games.first.number %> </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот код действия #index:

```
  def index
    @a = Array(1..25)
    @d = number_nil

    @games = Game.all
  end
```

и в нём вы выбираете все игры и присваиваешь переменной @games.
А в представлении вы обращаетесь к одной игре, т.е. @game. Полагаю вам следует в представлении перечислять все игры и для каждой считать клацы.

```
<%- @games.each do |game| %>
   ...
      <p>Неправельный ответ : <%= game.number %></p>
   ...
<%- end %>
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но я нашол ошибку )

Answer (score 0):

В момент вывода, у тебя отсутствует переменная `@game`